# Chrome history Api returning unexpected results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, and I need to get certain timeslices of a user's browsing history (the past week, month, and year). However, some unexpected history items are showing up, namely those that are older than the specified start date. For example, the definition I'm using of a week ago (ms since epoch) is:

```
var microsecondsPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
searchDepth = (new Date).getTime() - microsecondsPerWeek;
```

I then perform the search like so:

```
chrome.history.search({
'text': '',                // Return every history item...
'startTime': searchDepth   // accessed less than x time ago.
}, 
...
```

Console logging for the time values returned by this search shows some unexpected results. Namely, messages like this:

```
Tue Apr 14 2015 21:31:52 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tue Apr 14 2015 21:30:26 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tue Jan 27 2015 12:55:15 GMT-0800 (PST)
Fri Mar 20 2015 12:17:55 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Sat Apr 11 2015 19:50:27 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

As of the time of this question, one week ago was April 14th. So my question is, why am I seeing returned results for January 27th, March 20th, and April 11th? It seems strange, since most of the search code I'm using is pulled from a [Google example of the History API](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/history/showHistory/typedUrls.js?revision=119883). Any ideas? I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't make it out.

Comment: Nitpick: it's milliseconds, not microseconds.

Comment: looks like a bug in chrome. If you give the function an endtime as well does it still do this?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately so. I tried giving it an endtime of (new Date).getTime(), but had the same results.